# Could a map file / TECkit generate a TeX command?

Tags: xetex

> **This is not an important question.**

I am just wondering if we could generate a command using a map file for [TECkit](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=TECkitRecentChanges). Or do we have to use character classes for this task, see pages 14 and 15 in the [XeTeX reference guide](http://ftp.cstug.cz/pub/tex/CTAN/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf), or LuaTeX instead?

In this example I tried to type `a` and get a `{\ae a}` command. At the TeX level I am defining the `\ae` part. This is my non-working experiment. My `test.map` file looks like this:

```
; This is test.map file...
LHSName "input (keyboard)"
RHSName "output (glyphs)"
Define a U+0061
pass(Unicode)
a > U+007BU+005CU+0061U+0065U+0020U+0061U+007D
```

I run this line to get `test.tec` file:

```
teckit_compile test.map -o test.tec
```

I run `xelatex mal-teckit-test.tex`, where this is the content of the TeX file:

```
% run: xelatex mal-teckit-test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\ae{\color{green}}
\setmainfont[Mapping=test]{lmroman10-bolditalic.otf}
\begin{document}
a {\ae b}
\end{document}
```

The preview of the result is this (first picture), the wanted result is shown on the second picture.

[image: mwe, actual result]
[image: mwe, wanted result]

Comment: I  am not sure, but I think that teckit operates on node level, not macro or token levels. You may have better luck with LuaTeX and `process_input_buffer` callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it can’t. The result of applying TECkit maps in XeTeX is used much after macro expansion, so it is typeset literally.