# Package/help for using Yi Script?

Tags: fonts, languages, alphabet

I am doing work on Yi (Nuosu) language, and would like to incorporate the Yi script into my work in LaTeX. I have looked around and can't find a package that gives support for Yi script. Is there a package? If not, is there any way I can have LaTeX recognize the Yi Unicode?

Comment: I think it would be possible to use Noto Sans Yi (https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-yiii) or Nuosu SIL (https://software.sil.org/nuosu/) with `luatex` or `xetex`, but I don’t know enough about the language to make a meaningful test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the answer, do you need a mapping file? e.g., with mapping latin to yi, you can type `jjo` and it produces `ꐥ`.

If you need to do only a few syllables, you can define individual macros for them, like `\newcommand\yipuo{^^^^a044}`.

Mapping is useful when you need to type a lot of text and do not have a keyboard or input method editor for the script.

A mapping file looks like this:

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "latin-to-yi" ; 
RHSName "UNICODE"


pass(Unicode)

;=====================================
U+006A U+006A U+006F <> U+A425
U+0064 U+0064 U+0075 <> U+A14D
U+0061 U+0070 <> U+A00B
;===================================
```

(I called the file `latin-to-yi.map`)

and it is compiled into a `.tec` binary file with `teckit_compile`.

Then the mapping is called into play with the `Mapping=`filename option when the font is declared.

Like this:

```
% compile with xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\yi[Mapping=latin-to-yi]{Noto Sans Yi}
\begin{document}
{\yi jjo ddu ap jjo }: everything’s fine, there’s nothing the matter
% from https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Yi/lesson_01.html
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: yi mapped]

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to download teckit, but I don't know how to use teckit_compile. Is there a tutorial on the stackexchange you could direct me towards?

Comment: @Jackirab  Asking a separate question will probably get a faster answer. I haven't seen any tutorials. `Teckit_compile.exe` is a program. It takes a plain-text mapping file as input, and you compile the `.map` file into a binary `.tec` file by doing `teckit_compile foo.map` (if your `.map` file is called `foo.map`) on your command line.

Comment: @Jackirab Some questions I've found useful are: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176709/could-a-map-file-teckit-generate-a-tex-command

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446546/switch-between-fraktur-and-standard-fonts

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218318/how-add-my-own-ligature/218326#218326

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/create-my-own-mapping-for-xetex-fonts

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements are somewhat vague, but if what you need are some short texts written in the Yi script, here is how you can do it with `babel` 3.38, just released, and `luatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\babelprovide[import=ii, onchar=ids fonts]{yi}

\babelfont[yi]{rm}{FandolSong}

\begin{document}

Thus ꆏꂴꐊ (ne miep qo) “You walk in front of me” and ꉢꊁꐊ (nga wax qo)
“I’ll follow directly behind you”.

\end{document}
```

(Also from babelstone.co.uk.)

[image: Babel an yi]

Answer (score 2):

`babel` seems not (yet) to offer very much help with Nuosu, although it does recognize `sichuanyi`.  However, for short texts or isolated words, something like this suffices:

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\yi{NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
{\yi ꐥꅍꀋꐥ}: everything’s fine, there’s nothing the matter
% from https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Yi/lesson_01.html
\end{document}
```

[image: output]